# react-native-sqlite-storage - no such table

Tags: sqlite, react-native

Someone knows the best way to connect react-native-sqlite-storage? My debugger gets "no such table: nameOfTable (code 1)" after a query.

I should get "id","name" and "last name" from a table named "person". 
I have connected my prepopulated database ("mioDB") located in "/android/app/src/main/assets/mioDB.db".

This is my little code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput,View,Text,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { openDatabase } from "react-native-sqlite-storage";

let mioDB = openDatabase('mioDB');

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name:'',
      lastName:''
    };
  }

  showData=()=>{
    alert('name: '+this.state.name+' lastName: '+this.state.lastName);
  };

  listOfNames=()=>{
    try{
      mioDB.transaction((statement)=>{
        console.log('****************');
        statement.executeSql('SELECT * FROM person',[],(statement,results)=>{
          console.log('****************');
          var len = results.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              let row = results.rows.item(i);
              console.log(`Record: ${row.name}`);
            }
        });
      });
    }catch(error){
      alert(error);
    }    
  };    

  render(){    
    return(
      <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
        <TextInput style={{fontSize:20}} placeholder='name' onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({name:text})}/>
        <TextInput style={{fontSize:20}} placeholder='lastName' onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({lastName:text})}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width:150,height:50}} onPress={this.showData}><Text>Create db</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width:150,height:50}} onPress={this.listOfNames}><Text>Show database</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[from the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJFL8.png)

I don't know where it is wrong because the system to connect is easy

Comment: As per the document (https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-6---adjust-opendatabase-call), pre-populated file should be under `www` directory, but the path that you have shared is not under `www` directory.  Also for pre-populated DB, `openDatabase` takes an object. Please make these two changes and try.

Comment: But in the same link I readed "For Android, the www directory is always relative to the assets directory for the app: src/main/assets", then I replaced the "www/mioDB.db" in the assets folder, It works !! Thank You Prasun

Comment: Let me make it part of the answer so that anyone looking for the same can reach the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the document ([react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-6---adjust-opendatabase-call)), the pre-populated file should be under `www` directory, but the path that you have shared is not under `www` directory. Also for pre-populated DB, openDatabase takes an object of the form

```
{name : "testDB", createFromLocation : "~data/mioDB.db"}
```

Here `data` is a subdirectory of `www` directory.

Please make these two changes and try.

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Comment: Sure @shira, can you please let me know your issue, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: do u have facebook or something that i can connect with you ?

Comment: I've built all the functions of insert,update,delete,fetch but for some reason it doesn't work for me and I need help with that

Comment: @shira `https://github.com/yasinfmd/youtubeSourceCode/blob/main/rn%20sqlite/App.js` will help you

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite silently creates the database file if it does not exist. So if
> you've got the path wrong, you are opening an empty database file,
> which of course does not contain any tables. Make sure the database
> file exists there and it is not empty

**You have to do some options**

**1-** Create a directory named `www` under the `assets folder` in `android/app/src/main/assets` and place your DB here.(**for example I have a Db with the name of** `common.db`)

##### NOTE

If the `assets folder` dose does not exist create it.

**2-** Open your database like the following:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'
....

const db= await SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'common', createFromLocation: "~common.db", location: 'Library' })
```

**3-** Now you can execute your query

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM person", [], (tx, results) => {
      results.rows.raw().forEach(item => {
        console.log(item)
      })
    })
})
```